# How to check if image is already stored in a site's post database? (network)

Tags: php, images, database, multisite

I currently have configured Wordpress so that a post can be copied to other sites within a Wordpress network. However, a post may be broadcast more than once, and I want to check if the image is already published into that site's `wp_posts` table.

As an example, let's say an image has the image path:

```
/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/an_image.jpg
```

All images are stored by the network within this setup of folders (rather than the default `/blogs.dir/files/`).

In other words, can Wordpress query the database to check if this is already in the table, or does it need to be written as a PHP database query?

Comment: Please make clear _what you already know_ (DB ID, Blog ID, etc.) and what you want to know.

Comment: @kaiser Only the URL of the file is known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a database query is possible with WordPress:

```
function is_image_in_network( $image_name )
{
    global $wpdb;
    $image = "uploads/2012/01/{$image_name}";
    $value = '%'.like_escape( $image ).'%';
    $blog_id = get_current_blog_id();
    $wpdb->set_blog_id( $blog_id );
    $image = $wpdb->get_var( 
        $wpdb->prepare( 
            "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} 
            WHERE  post_status = 'publish' 
            AND post_content LIKE '%s'"
            , $value 
        ) 
    );
    return is_null( $image ) ? false : true;
}
```

You can use it as function in your templates. Just add the image name, you're searching for as argument. The new "Template Tag" works like every default WP "Conditional Tag".

Is that `image.php` in the Question a typo?

I'm leaving the search string `%uploads/2012/01/an_image%` without an extension so it can catch all the images (original and thumbnails).

<sup>Documentation: [Class_Reference/wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).</sup>

Comment: +1, but you're missing the `like_prepare()`.

Comment: @kaiser, like what¿! I cannot find that in google or core :s

Comment: Sry, replied to Rarst & toscho in chat something with `prepare()`. :P Actually it's [`like_escape()`](http://queryposts.com/function/like_escape/) and you'll likely need to add it like this: `'%'.like_escape($foo).'%'`.

Comment: @kaiser, one more to the function bag, looks like escaped now, thx. I cannot help but see that this function is staring at me `e_e` ;)

Comment: Or maybe it's `o.O` ;)

Comment: I wrapped it in a function name/built a conditional tag out of it. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @kaiser, at all, you just made those lines of code happier, now they belong, `liko.Oscape()`

Comment: And sorry yes the `.php` was a typo!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way *should* be to use [`wp_attachment_is_image()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_attachment_is_image/).

```
if ( ! wp_attachment_is_image( $post_ID ) )
{
    // process needed tasks
}
```

Note that this only takes those files into account that have a header of [`image/*`](http://de.selfhtml.org/diverses/mimetypen.htm#uebersicht) *or* an extension of `'jpg', 'jpeg', 'jpe', 'gif', 'png'`.

*This is not tested.*

Comment: Unfortunately I won't know the ID in the database, only the image URL. Any ideas here?

Comment: _"(...) I won't know the ID (...)"_ ... do you _don't want to know_ or you _don't know_ ... ?

Comment: I don't know - I'm checking whether an image I'm taking from another blog in the network is in the blog I am checking.

Comment: 1st: How are you "taking" this image? 2nd: @brasofilo has a working query for you.